# Is it possible to make URLs conditional with django?

Tags: django

I'm using the middleware to detect the subdomain and place a corresponding object in the request scope. Would it be possible to take it further and declare that the subdomain implements these urls but not those?

Something like?

```
if request.subdomain.is_blue:
     include(these.urls)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the urlconf is executed at startup time, not for each request; so you don't have the opportunity to include or not according to the URL used to acess.

the best would be to write your own middleware, or a restricting decorator (like @login_required), it's quite easy to write your own decorator (i like them more than middlewares for most specific tasks)

Comment: A decorator like  "@blue_required" does sound like a tidy solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can poke around with request.urlconf, but that can [break things](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-developers@googlegroups.com/msg20948.html)